# Android Sqlite no result

Tags: android, sqlite

what do you think my problem is.

I am querying a sqlite database.
This code doesn't give any result.

```
String sql = " select _id from MYTABLE where  _id = ?  ";
  Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {"5653"}) ;
```

but if I am executing the query without parameters like this:

```
String sql = " select _id from MYTABLE where  _id = 5653  ";
  Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null) ;
```

One row is returned as expected.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the values are bound as strings, and that column is (i am guessing) an int. so the where clause will end up being

```
where _id = "5653"
```

From rawQuery javadoc for selectionArgs -

> You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String sql = " select _id from MYTABLE where  _id = '5653'  ";
```